# Does the "three times" count still apply if we use "detergent"?

Tags: fiqh, taharah, hanafi

I know (In Hanafi school of law or Madhab), I need to wash clothes three times to make them clean(pure). But the rule doesn't say anything about using detergent or chemicals, which can effectively remove impurity (Najas).

Does the same rule apply if we use *detergent*?

Comment: Is it even possible to remove it with detergent by washing it once or twice? I think you'd need to scrub it after washing, which should end up counting for more, and it spins more than three times in the washing machine.

Comment: @Muz spining doesn't count as times. You need to wash cloth for each time in new water also rinse the cloth to remove every drop of water. That is the rule

Comment: do you ask only for hanafi answers or for any answer?

Comment: @qdinar I follow hanafi fiqh so wanted to know that. But any other answer can be written as long as you note about the fiqh. Also I'm not sure if the hukm is same in other majHab/fiqh

Comment: @Anwar what if somebody answers just based on quran and hadiths?

Comment: @qdinar Hanafi fiqh is based on quran and hadiths.

Comment: @Anwar is it ok for you if somebody writes an answer with links to hadiths and ayats he/she knows and his/her explanation but without any links to nor cites from hanafi books or other mazhabs' scholars' books?

Comment: @qdinar For me, No. But I am not entirely sure of the site policy about it.

Comment: earlier you said "But any other answer can be written as long as you note about the fiqh" - so, any answer of other famous mazhabs are ok for you, but you do not need a fiqh made by ijtihad (independent reasoning)? then, i think 4 sunni mazhabs are ok for you, what about other sunni mazhabs and jafari mazhab ie shia mazhab? as i know site policy is that answer should be according to requirements set by questioner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on the way of washing, which is one of two ways:

1. washing in a container (with hands)
2. washing in running water (includes washing machine) or pouring water on the cloth.

In washing in a container, you must wash three times and squeeze in every time.

In washing in running water, you have two cases depending on the sort of najasa, whether it's seen or not:

- If the najasa is seen, the mass (Aein) of it must be removed, even in one time. The taste of it must be removed as well. If the colour or smell of it were hard to be removed that will be OK.
- If the najasa is unseen, water must get in and out of  the cloth three times (this will be fulfilled in the washing machine).

[*Ahmad bin Mohamad Al-Tahtawi, Hashia on Maraqi Alfalah, p. 159*](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-11993#page-171)

So you can conclude that chemicals wont make a difference except in the case of removing the mass of najasa because the process will be faster.

Comment: Assalamu 'alaikum and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange! Answers in this site are expected to be packed with references and/or citations. As it currently stands, you answer suffers the lack of sources. Please edit it and add some sources/proofs to make the answer more acceptable.

Comment: Wa'laykom assalam, thanks for the advice brother, I have added the reference but it's in Arabic.

Comment: You're most welcome brother, regarding Arabic citations: although it's preferred to add English citations, it's not mandatory, no problem with Arabic citations. (we've already discussed that on meta [here](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/465/167) ).

Comment: Thanks brother for the answer. I was expecting similar. So, If I wash cloth in washing machine, it is ok, right. Mind that, we have a machine which does not change water.I think, in that case, I need to wash three times also. Please clarify this. +1 for the good answer.

Comment: I'm afraid you must wash three times with squeeze in every time.
but if this is hard for you, you can follow another mathhab,
for example in Maliki mathhab, the taste of najasa must be removed. the colour and smell of it must be removed if easy, 
otherwise it's not obligatory. regardless of the way of washing, the sort of najasa and the number of washing times.
http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-21604/page-79