# Does the “three times” count still apply if we use “detergent”?

Tags: sharia, shiism

It is needed to wash clothes three times to make them clean(pure). But the rule doesn't say anything about using detergent or chemicals, which can effectively remove impurity (Najas).

Does the same rule apply if we use detergent?

*Jafari Fiqh view is preferred but view of other schools is welcomed.*

Comment: similar: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/does-the-three-times-count-still-apply-if-we-use-detergent

Answer (score 1):

According to [Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence) of [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) Yes, the “three times” count still apply if we use “detergent”. But “three times” is only for situation the water used is Under-Kurr water.

After removal of Najasat if water is [Under-Kurr Water](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/taharat.html#25) three times of washing is needed. But if water is [Kurr Water](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/taharat.html#16) after removal of Najasat one washing is enough.

---

**Notes:**

- In Islam rules, clean is different of Islamic pure.
- Najasat means the Najis thing like Stool or blood.

---

**References:**

[Chapter: Mutahhirat Title: Water](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/mutahhirat.html#150)  from  [Risalah](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/) of Ayatullah al Uzama Syed Ali al-Husaini [Seestani](http://sistani.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The ruling has to do with the najaasah itself. Once the najaasah is removed from the clothes, they become taahir (pure). Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah said that there is no specific number of washings required for najaasah to be removed.

[Source](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/6725/wash%20clothes)

Comment: Welcome to Islam Stack Exchange, and thanks for giving an answer that's packed up with citation. However, it would be much better if you answer had more details, answers that just quote from other sites might not be acceptable as other sites might also be unacceptable references :)

Answer (score 0):

If we use "detergent", does the count "three times" still apply?
Impurity should be washed three times with a little water, but in deafness and current it is also a precaution three times, although it is preferable in deafness and current once.

Ref: https://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?id=10&pid=10&tid=-1